# [VBA][MULTISELECT] Copying multiselected files to Active Workbook not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post here, so I'll try to summarize the situation.

I would like to point out that my programming skills are zero, so I took pieces of several codes and tried to understand the logic behind it to create this macro. Be kind.

**- The Code goal:** Copy and Paste info from multiple selected files to Active Workbook.

**- The Steps:**

Step 1: Create Worksheet in the opened file

Step 2: Place Headings on the Created Worksheet

Step 3: Select multiple Files to copy information from

Step 4: Copy contents of the selected files to the Worksheet created in step 1

**- The code itself**

```
Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile, headers() As Variant
Dim wks, wksDst, DstSht, wsCopy, wsDest, ws, wksCurSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook, wb As Workbook
Dim CopyLastRow, DestLastRow As Long

'Step 1
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidate_Data").Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        With ActiveWorkbook
            Set DstSht = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
            DstSht.Name = "Consolidate_Data"
        End With

'Step 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidate_Data")

headers() = Array("Superhero", "City", "State", "Country", "Publisher", "Demographics", _
    "Planet", "Flying Abilities", "Vehicle", "Sidekick", "Powers")
For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    With ws
    .Rows(1).Value = "" 'This will clear out row 1
    For i = LBound(headers()) To UBound(headers())
        .Cells(1, 1 + i).Value = headers(i)
    Next i
    .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    End With
Next ws

'Step 3
fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Selecione os arquivos", MultiSelect:=True)

If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1

                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)
Next
                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
Next

'Step 4

  Set wsCopy = wbkSrcBook.Sheets("Relatório_Ouvidoria_monitoria")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Novo(a) Planilha do Microsoft Excel.xlsm").Sheets("Consolidate_Data")

  CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  DestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                wbkSrcBook.Sheets("Relatório_Ouvidoria_monitoria").Range("A2:M" & CopyLastRow).Copy _
                wsDest.Range("A" & DestLastRow)
                wbkSrcBook.Close Savechanges:=False
            Next

            MsgBox "Foram consolidados " & countFiles & " arquivos" & vbCrLf & "Foram importadas " & countSheets & " planilhas", Title:="Merge Excel files"

  Else
        MsgBox "Nenhum arquivo selecionado", Title:="Merge Excel files"
End If
End If
End Sub
```

**- The Problem:** On Step 4 (or I believe so), the macro is copying information only from the first file I'm selecting, leaving others behind.

I don't know if it's important: every file I'm selecting have only one worksheet with the same name. Unfortunately It isn't an option to change the worksheet name, though.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code:

```
For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
  countFiles = countFiles + 1
  Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)
Next
```

You are opening each workbook in a loop and Setting wbkSrcBook to it.  By the end of the loop, all workbooks may be open, but wbkSrcBook is now only Set to the last workbook in the loop.  Then later, in a different loop, you (try to) operate on each sheet in that, but then close after the first sheet anyway:

```
For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
   wbkSrcBook.Sheets("Relatório_Ouvidoria_monitoria").Range("A2:M" & CopyLastRow).Copy _
   wsDest.Range("A" & DestLastRow)
   wbkSrcBook.Close Savechanges:=False
Next
```

You already have all the workbook names in an array after using the filepicker.  You iterate through that array to open each, count them for some reason, then only operate on the last opened book in a separate loop.

Instead you could try to move your copy/paste logic into the same loop you use to open each workbook.  Open each book-> copy its data to destination, close it, open the next.

(at work so don't have time to re-code this, and I would comment this but don't have enough points to leave comments.)  Hope this helps a little.